# Showing a node with a Views?

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I have a bundle "Text" and bundle "Protocol". The "Protocol" bundle has a field of Entity Reference type which links the "protocol" node with texts that were accepted during that protocol. (I.e. the join is somewhat like "Protocol"->"Text") Also Protocol has following fields: a protocol number (integer) and a date (date-iso)

While viewing "Text"-type node there will be shown information about the corresponding protocol:its number and acceptance date (mention them above).

So the question is: is it a good practice to show this pages via Views? Owing to its Relations feature, obtaining of information related to the corresponding protocol is really easy. But idea itself seems to me being of kinda "bad Drupal way", because there is a standard way of displaying nodes in Drupal.

If the Views is really bad idea, then how should I obtain the protocol's number and date, from tpl.php (or preprocessor function)? Any variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views can be a little heavy, and if you don't need the module it's lighter just to drop it.

If you just want to grab some info for a template, you could also do it with [Entity Field Queries](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).